# How to test node's fs.watch()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a function that uses `fs.watch`. Example below.

```
function listenToFileChange() {
  fs.watch(fileLocation, "utf-8", async function(event, fileName) {
    if (event === "change") {
      dbUp.push(fileName, function() {});
    }
  });
}
```

I am trying to test this using jest; but it's unclear to me how to do it properly. There is probable looping.

```
jest.mock("loadBaselineFile", () => jest.fn());

describe("Tests listenToFileChange", () => {
  test(`GIVEN endpoint /info
        WHEN make a request and database and data loader are healthy 
        THEN return an answer with status: pass, statusCode: 200, type:application/health+json`, async () => {
    listenToFileChange();
    fs.writeFileSync(
      `dataLoader/1.json`,
      "{id: '1', amount: '12'}",
      "utf8"
    );
    expect(loadBaselineFile.mock.calls.length).toBeCalledWith(1);
  });

});
```

Can someone please help me understand how to properly test this and make sure that my test is performant.